# I need to add a delay between displaying labels in VB but i seem to be having trouble

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, visual-studio-2010

i am creating a simple application for 'fun' where when the user opens the application, it pretents to connect to a device and shut it down. I want it to slowly display the labels like

```
Connecting to device...
(wait like 10 seconds)
Exploiting registry...
(wait like 10 seconds)
```

and so on, well as u can see from the code below i used `system.threading.thread.sleep(2000)` it works but it pauses the whole code and since this shutdown.vb is opened from a separate main.vb it just messes with whole execution and dosent work! Is there any other way other then the thread sleep? I just need a pause between each line, Thanks! The code is below!

```
Public Class shutdown
    Private Sub shutdown_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Label2.Hide()
        Label3.Hide()
        Label4.Hide()
        shutdownConnect()
    End Sub
    Private Sub shutdownConnect()
        Label2.Show()
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)
        Label3.Show()
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)
        Label4.Show()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Use a `Timer` for that.

Comment: How tho, @OneFineDay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `Timer`. Set the label's visibilty to False in the designer then change that with timer.

```
Public Class shutdown
 Private counter As Integer
 Private Sub shutdown_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    timer1.Start()
 End Sub
 Private Sub timer1_Tick() Handles timer1.Tick
    counter += 1
    Select Case counter
      Case 1
       Label2.Visible = True
      Case 2
       Label3.Visible = True
      Case 3
       Label4.Visible = True
       timer1.Stop()
       counter = 0 'reset for next time
    End Select
 End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no point hiding or showing anything in or from the `Load` event handler because the form hasn't even been displayed at that point.  Your use of `Thread.Sleep` is also highly inappropriate.  Sleeping the UI thread is something that should pretty much NEVER be done.

The proper approach here would be to start by setting the `Visible` property of `Label3` and `Label4` to `False` in the designer.  That way, simply displaying the form naturally will display `Label2` but not the others.  You would also use a `Timer` with an `Interval` of 2000 and, in the `Tick` event handler, `Show` the next `Label`.  You might add the `Label`s to a queue or some other collection and then, when they are all displayed, `Stop` the `Timer`.